# Why am I getting the error - load error: openssl -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jruby.ext.openssl.ASN1?

Tags: java, openssl, jruby, jruby-openssl

I am trying to embed `JRuby` in a Java project. I am using `jruby-complete-1.7.4.jar` and `ScriptingContainer`.

For some reason, the following script throws error.

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
container.runScriptlet("require 'net/https'");
```

This fails with the exception

```
load error: openssl -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jruby.ext.openssl.ASN1.
```

This happens only in few computers. I don't have `jruby-openssl` and bouncy castle gem installed. My class path contains only `jruby-complete-1.7.4.jar`. I am wondering why this error happens and what should be done to work around this problem? How can this work on
a computer and fails on a different one? Any help to debug the issue would be great.

Jruby version - 1.7.4
System - Mac OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 0):

You do not need jruby-openssl separately .. it should be bundled with jruby jar.. make sure you do not have any old jruby-openssl or bouncycastle installed.

Comment: This is the common answer appearing everywhere. This might be true for standalone `jruby` not for embedded version. I am using `ScriptingContainer` which gets the gems from the jar file and what we specify in the `setLoadPaths()`. I don't think it has anything to do with gems installed at the system level. Or am I missing something?